# Negation of a statement validation

Tags: analysis, logic, solution-verification

Let the statement be : "For any two real numbers $x,y,$ if $x<y$ there is some z $\in$ S so that $x < z < y$ (where S $\subset$ R). My negation was as follows : "there exists an $x,y,$ s.t. for all z $\in$ S, if $x < y$ then $z \leq x$ AND $z \geq y$".

I'm quite uncertain about the logic of the last part but I'm unsure if the negation of $ x < z < y$ has to negate both equalities separately or (which seems more logical now that I think about it) using a sort of de Morgan's laws we will replace the AND with an OR.

Comment: It is thrice wrong: 1) the negation of $x<z<y$ is $z\le x$ **or** $z\ge y$; 2) the negation of "if $x<y$ then $P(x,y)$" is not "**if** $x<y$ **then** $\neg P(x,y)$". It is $x<y$ **and** $\neg P(x,y)$; 3) the negation of "$x<y\implies \exists z,Q(x,y,z)$" contains $\forall z$ *after* $x<y$, not *before*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your negated statement has a couple of issues. For one, the "if... then..." structure should dissappear and be replaced with an "... and..." structure. Furthermore, DeMorgan's Law has not been properly applied.

Hereafter I explain what the correct negation is, beginning with your initial statement in natural language, which reads as follows:

**For any two real numbers $x,y,$ if $x<y$, then there exists at least one $z \in S \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $x<z<y$.**

In the language of FOL, this translates as

$$ \forall x \forall y [ x<y \to \exists z[x<z<y]] $$

where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z \in S \subset \mathbb{R}$. We can restate "$x<z<y$" equivalently as "$x<z$ and $z<y$." Thus, we rewrite the above formula as

$$ \forall x \forall y [ x<y \to \exists z[x<z \wedge z<y]] $$

and the negation of this formula is

$
\begin{array}{ll}
\neg \forall x \forall y [ x<y \to \exists z[x<z \wedge z<y]] & \\
\exists x \exists y \neg [ x<y \to \exists z[x<z \wedge z<y]] & \text{Negation Rules for Quantifiers} \\
\exists x \exists y \neg [ \neg (x<y) \vee \exists z[x<z \wedge z<y]] & \text{Implication Rule} \\
\exists x \exists y[ \neg \neg (x<y) \wedge \neg \exists z[x<z \wedge z<y]] & \text{DeMorgan's Law} \\
\exists x \exists y[ x<y \wedge \neg \exists z[x<z \wedge z<y]] & \text{Double Negation Law} \\
\exists x \exists y[ x<y \wedge \forall z \neg [x<z \wedge z<y]] & \text{Negation Rules for Quantifiers} \\
\exists x \exists y[ x<y \wedge \forall z [\neg (x<z) \vee \neg (z<y)]] & \text{DeMorgan's Laws} \\
\exists x \exists y[ x<y \wedge \forall z [x \ge z \vee z \ge y]] & \text{Definition of $\ge$} \\
\end{array}
$

So, the negation of your initial statement reads as follows:

**There exists real numbers $x,y$ such that $x<y$ and, for every $z \in S \subset \mathbb{R}$, either $z \le x$ or $z \ge y$.**